# Using LIKE "%something%" in FMDatabase for iOS

Tags: iphone, fmdb

I'm not sure if this is true or not, but I was told that FMDatabase performs better if you do this

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM db where col=?"];
FMResultSet *rs = [theDatabase executeQuery:query, columnToLookFor];

vs

NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM db where col='columnToLookFor'"];
FMResultSet *rs = [theDataBase executeQuery:query];
```

So we have a search query that does this:

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT Symbol, Category FROM Symbols where Category like \"%%%@%%\" or Symbol like \"%%%@%%\" group by Symbol, Category order by Category", searchtext, searchtext];
FMResultSet *rs = [theDatabase executeQuery:query];
```

I'm trying to change this to:

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT Symbol, Category FROM Symbols where Category like \"%%?%%\" or Symbol like \"%%?%%\" group by Symbol, Category order by Category"];
FMResultSet *rs = [theDatabase executeQuery:query, searchtext, searchtext];
```

However in the second form with the ?, my FMResultSet is 0 and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in this scenario.  Would this speed up our search at all?  Or is it more of a bad database design for this functionality to take so long.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no reason why one would work and the other would not work, assuming that your searchtext variable from the first one is a question mark, since you are putting that literal into the SQL string in the second. You might want to change the two lines to this:

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithString:@"SELECT Symbol, Category FROM Symbols where Category like '%%?%%' or Symbol like '%%?%%' group by Symbol, Category order by Category"];
FMResultSet *rs = [theDatabase executeQuery:query];
```

Also, I would do this before the lines just to see what the SQL is looking like when it is being processed by FMDB:

```
[theDatabase setTraceExecution:YES];
```

EDIT: Try changing it to this and see what the trace execution says:

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithString:@"SELECT Symbol, Category FROM Symbols where Category like '%%?%%' or Symbol like '%%?%%' group by Symbol, Category order by Category"];
FMResultSet *rs = [theDatabase executeQuery:query, searchtext, searchtext, nil];
```

Comment: Thanks for the setTraceExecution.  That helps see what is happening.  In the '%%?%%' case, the query to FMDatabase is being just that:   '%?%'.  I doesn't seem to be registering my searchtext in for the ?.  Is it because I need whitespace around the ?.

Comment: Ah, I see what you are doing, it has been a while since I used the FMDB stuff. What happens if you change the second line as my edit above shows?

Answer (score -1):

```
FMResultSet *result = [db executeQuery: @"SELECT * FROM channels_list WHERE type = 'person' AND members LIKE (?)",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%%@%%", userID]];
```